# align number element when countdown reaches one-digit numbers

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a simple number count down code. The code works fine except one little annoying issue.

The problem is when we reach one-digit numbers an extra space appears between number and Seconds word like

`9  Seconds` instead of the desired result that would be `9 Seconds`.

I've tried to set text alignment in both CSS and HTML code but it seems that it doesn't solve the issue!

```js
// get HTML ids we need
let counterUpperText = document.getElementById("counterUpperText");
let secondsUpperText = document.getElementById("secondsUpperText");


// create countdown number
let timeleft = 14;
  counterUpperText.innerHTML = `${timeleft}`;
  upperTextAnimeShow(counterUpperText);
  
let savedTimer = setInterval(function(){
  //console.log(timeleft);
  timeleft--;
  counterUpperText.innerHTML = `${timeleft}`;
  
  if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(savedTimer);
    console.log("done");
    secondsUpperText.innerHTML = ``;
    counterUpperText.innerHTML = `Done!`;
 
    return;
  }
  
}, 1000);

// create animations

    upperTextAnimeShow(counterUpperText);

    upperTextAnimeHide(secondsUpperText);
    upperTextAnimeShow(secondsUpperText);
    
    secondsUpperText.innerHTML = `Seconds`;



// animation functions
function upperTextAnimeShow(el){
     el.classList.add("upperTextAnimeShow");
     el.classList.remove("upperTextAnimeHide");
};

function upperTextAnimeHide(el){
     el.classList.remove("upperTextAnimeShow");
     el.classList.add("upperTextAnimeHide");
};
```

```css
.upperTextContainer{
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 10vw;
    top: 40vh;
    height: 16vh;
    width: 29vw;   
    /*outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;*/
}

.upperTexts{
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2vw;
    color: rgb(215, 215, 215);
    left: 0.4vw;
    opacity: 0;
   
}

#secondsUpperText{
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 2vw;
    color: rgb(215, 215, 215);
    left: 3.4vw;
    opacity: 0;

}

.upperTextAnimeShow {
    animation: upperTextShow 0.3s ease-in-out;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards ;
}

.upperTextAnimeHide {
    animation: upperTextHide 0.3s ease-in-out;  
    animation-fill-mode: forwards ;
}

@-webkit-keyframes upperTextShow {
  0%    { opacity: 0; top: 10vh }
  100%  { opacity: 1; top: -8vh }
}

@-webkit-keyframes upperTextHide {
   from { opacity: 1; top: -8vh }
   to   { opacity: 0; top:  10vh }
}
```

```html
<div class = "upperTextContainer">
 <p id="counterUpperText" class="upperTexts" style="text-align: right;"></p>
 <p id="secondsUpperText" class="upperTexts"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is the `position:absolute` for the elements

Comment: I need all positions absolute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#counterUpperText` does not have a `width` and it is aligned to the left of its container.

When you reach a 1 digit number the `p#counterUpperText` element will resize to the width of the text

Answer (score 2):

try to add this.. its working

**css**

```
.upperTextContainer{
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 10vw;
    top: 40vh;
    height: 16vh;
    width: 29vw;   
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    /*outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;*/
}

.upperTexts{
    position: static;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2vw;
    color: rgb(215, 215, 215);
    left: 0.4vw;
    opacity: 0;

}

#secondsUpperText{
    position: static;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 2vw;
    color: rgb(215, 215, 215);
    left: 3.4vw;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-left:3px;

}

.upperTextAnimeShow {
    animation: upperTextShow 0.3s ease-in-out;
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards ;
}

.upperTextAnimeHide {
    animation: upperTextHide 0.3s ease-in-out;  
    animation-fill-mode: forwards ;
}

@-webkit-keyframes upperTextShow {
  0%    { opacity: 0; top: 10vh }
  100%  { opacity: 1; top: -8vh }
}

@-webkit-keyframes upperTextHide {
   from { opacity: 1; top: -8vh }
   to   { opacity: 0; top:  10vh }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers plus one but I really need all positions absolute...